# How to pick up elements from nested "div"

Tags: javascript, cypress

I have following elements to be picked up in cypress.

```
render(){
        return(
            <div id = "d1">
                {this.state.data.map(
                (data,index) => (
                    <div id = "d2">
                        <h1 id = "txt1"> {data.title} </h1><br/><h2 id = "txt2">{data.author}</h2><br/><span id = "txt3">{data.article}</span><hr/>
                    </div>
                )
                )}
            </div>
        )
    }
```

I am learning cypress now. I am not really sure how to pick up the elements from div. i.e. the inner div and "title" and "header" elements.

Comment: Please [don't add tags to question titles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19190/133056).

Comment: First I would change your screen name. Ha ha. can you put the actual HTML and not the code that renders the HTML. I will try to answer below

Answer (score 2):

To find the `title` of `h1`, you could try the below code. Inside the equal bracket, you should give the 'real title' name to verify in the assertion part;

```
cy.get('#d2>h1').invoke('text')
      .then((text)=>{
        const title = text;
        expect(title).to.equal("typeherethedata.title");        
      })
```

or

```
cy.get('#txt1').invoke('text')
          .then((text)=>{
            const title = text;
            expect(title).to.equal("typeherethedata.title");        
          })
```

Comment: By using `expect` inside a `.then()` block you will lose cypress' ability to automatically retry assertions until they succeed - that comes from a `.should()` block

Answer (score 2):

`cy.get("#d1")` will get you the div.  `cy.get("#txt1")` will get you the header  Then if you want to assert the title is what you expect (or anything else about the elements), you can add a [`.should()`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/should.html)

```
cy.get("#txt1")
  .should("contain", "Your title here")
```